# Django rest framework how to get foreign key value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two basic classes and i have a serializer like this:

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def get_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = super(SomeSelializer, self).get_fields()
        user = self.context['view'].request.user
        fields['project'].queryset = fields['project'].queryset.filter(user=user)
        return fields

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'project', 'user')
        read_only_fields = ('id','user')
```

Project field is a foreign key to model project. How can I get some field from project instead its id?

When I'm trying this:

```
project = ProjectSerializer(source="project")
```

I get AttributeError: 'ProjectSerializer' object has no attribute 'queryset'

Comment: Perhaps you should show how you implemented `ProjectSerializer`

Comment: Also, it's not clear where you tried to use the `ProjectSerializer` to me

Answer (score 0):

You can't Access the Project field using the serializer. First in the python shell create the model's object and then serialize it using

```
serializer=ProjectSerializer(object)
```

You can then Access the Project field using -

```
 serializer.data.project
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to define a custom attribute using `SerializerMethodField` :

```
class SomeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    project_some_field = SerializerMethodField()
    # ...
    def get_project_some_field(self, obj):
        return obj.some_field
```

***NB***: by convention if the attribute name is `x`, the the method should be `get_x`

For more info check [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).